# JSON.stringify making json without canvas object names fabricjs

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, fabricjs

I'm having a problem with JSON.stringify method for canvas, using fabricjs. I draw some shapes on the canvas, rectangles and circles, that form a groups with text for each of them. Rectangles and circles have the name attribute that I dynamically specify. I then create the json using JSON.stringify(canvas) and send it to the server. The first time, json contains the name attribute for each object/group. I then load that json from server and draw it on a new canvas. Still everything is fine, all the attributes are present, but when I try to use the method again in order to send an updated version of json to the server(I change the color of a circle or something like that) the newly formed json doesn't contain name attribute for none of the objects from the canvas. So I have not deleted or added new objects, I have just changed the color of an object. I have followed the instructions from the site and added name to the toObject method like this:

```
rect.toObject = (function(toObject) {
    return function() {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
            name: this.name
        });
    };
})(rect.toObject);
```

And it works for the first json creation, but not for all consequential makings of json.